# How to find document's array item by its "_id" field in MongoDB (Mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema (NestJS + Mongoose):

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Listing {
  @Prop({
        type: [{
            bidderId: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, select: false, ref: User.name, index: true },
            amount: { type: Number, required: true },
            date: { type: Date, required: true }
        }],
        select: false
    })
        bids!: Bid[]
}
```

so basically every `listing` document has an array of `bids`.
now I notice that automatically mongoDB (or mongoose) creates `_id` field for every bid item I put into the `bids` array.

My question is, If I have a bid's `_id`, how can I query it's item from the listing's bids array? something like:

```
  // Adding a new bid to the listing, and retrieving the updated listing
  const listingWithAddedBid = await this.listingModel.findByIdAndUpdate(listingId, {
    $push: {
        bids: {
            $each: [{
                amount: bidInfo.amount,
                bidderId: new Types.ObjectId(user.id),
                date: new Date()
            }],
            $sort: { amount: -1 }
        }
    }
}, { new: true })

  // Getting the new bid's _id from the array (it will be at index 0 because we sort buy amount)
  const newBidId = listingWithAddedBid.bids[0]._id

  // here how can I query the entire bid item from the array with 'newBidId'? this won't work
  this.listingModel.findById(newBidId) // returns null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-_id-index

```
this.listingModel.findOne({ "bids._id": newBidId, {}, {}, (error, doc) =>
        {
         if (error) {
                ....
              }
              if (doc) {
                ....
              } else {
                ...//'Not Found';
              }
        });
```

Comment: By the way, is this indexed? or this will go through all the listings until a matched was found? because I  don't know `_id` of a nested object is indexed

Comment: edited, with some refrences